# filter / subset empty cells "" vs. NA. Why is subset (df, x =='') not the opposite of subset(df, x !=''). Bug in dplyr or base?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset, na

Consider a simple data frame you would like to filter:

`df <- data.frame(x = c('', '', NA, NA ))`

```
> df
     x
1     
2     
3 <NA>
4 <NA>
```

As expected `subset(df, x =='')` results in:

```
  x
1  
2
```

However, to my great surprise `subset(df, x !='')` results in:

```
[1] x
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Can anyone explain why `''` excludes `NA` when used with `==`, but it includes `NA` when used with `!=`. Can that be anything else than a bug in the R base function? The same applies to `dplyr` `filter()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%filter(x !='')
df%>%filter(x =='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a condition with `is.na`

```
subset(df, is.na(x) | x != "")
```

Because the `==` or `!=` returns `NA` whereever `NA` elements (i.e. any comparison with `NA` returns NA)  are present and not a logical vector.  `subset` and `filter` removes those `NA` rows as showed in the documentation of `?subset`

> subset - logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep: missing values are taken as false

and in `?filter`

> Note that when a condition evaluates to NA the row will be dropped, unlike base subsetting with [.

i.e.

```
with(df,  x != "")
#[1] FALSE FALSE    NA    NA

with(df, is.na(x) | x != "")
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thx akrun! However, I would not know which statement in ```?subset ``` tell you that ```NA``` rows are removed. Would be great to have some argument such as ```na.rm = FALSE```

Comment: @MrGISRocker It is the `subset` argument in `subset` function